# Why Xcode takes too much time to compile and run?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an Xcode project made in Swift. I am still working on it. Until the end of the last week everything was fine. However, this week I noticed it takes a lot of time to compile, I guess sometimes up to 2-5 minutes.
I am wondering, maybe it happens because of Swift, because for example we can create an extension in any source file, and it's accessible everywhere without importing anything. So while we get this convenient feature, we get performance issues.

Did anyone faced the same problems? I was thinking something was wrong with my OS X, but after formatting my Hard Drive, reinstalling OS X and Xcode, I still have the same issues.

Comment: one of the million reasons is e.g. you might have added some cocoapods to your project which were not really configured well.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode 6.3.1 and with Objective-C. In my case, just with asset catalogs and storyboards (when I edited something in one of them) and those files must recompile, compiling time rise up to 5 minutes. I believe is about XML files (both files save information in XML format) but I can not found the solution.

Comment: In my case I do not use any Pods or 3-rd Party Libraries. And it's very annoying and decreases my productivity as sometimes even when I only add a space or new line, it will take that long to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It same goes to me. What you need to do is restart the xcode. It happens mostly on xcode 6.3.1. Somethimes it takes 20-30 minutes to compile. Sometimes not!! There are not HDD, OS or RAM problem. It's because of latest xcode. Sometimes can be your cocoapod. You compile during cocoapod install new pod.